# Capturing this and forwarding the lambda to another lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a case where I need to pass a lambda into a free function, that will then invoke this lambda in another lambda. I have made an example below ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/qsf1aedWG)):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <map>
#include <format>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename RANGE, typename LAM>
auto foo(RANGE range, LAM&& lambda) {
    return range | std::views::transform(
                [&](const auto& element) { return lambda(element); });
}


class boo {
public:
    int add {2};
    
    void call_foo(){
        std::vector<int> d { 2,3,4,5,6};
        auto f = foo(d, [this](int i) { 
            std::cout << add << std::endl;
            return add + i; 
            });
        std::cout << f[0] << f[1] << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    boo b;
    b.call_foo(); // is no longer valid inside the lambda 
}
```

The code segfaults here:

```cpp
std::cout << add << std::endl;
```

This is basically because `this` becomes dangling inside the lambda. However, I don't understand why that occurs, and how to avoid this from happening.

I have also tried capturing the lambda inside `foo` by value and move/forward, but without a positive outcome.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with capturing `this`. Your `foo()` function is taking in the `vector` by value, thus copying it, and then returning a view into that copy, which is no longer alive by the time the view is read from after `foo()` exits. This smells like *undefined behavior* to me. Do you still have the problem if you change `foo()` to take in the `vector` by reference instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not `this` that becomes dangling, but `range` and the lambda you pass to `foo` becomes dangling. The reference to `range` held inside the `tranform_view` becomes danging as soon as `foo` returns and the lambda you pass to `foo` becomes dangling at the end of the full expression. You need a reference to `d` and capture the lambda by value in your inner lambda:

```cpp
template <typename RANGE, typename LAM>
auto foo(RANGE& range, LAM&& lambda) {
//            ^
    return range | std::views::transform(
                       [lambda](const auto& element) { return lambda(element); });
//                      ^^^^^^
}
```

Otherwise, the returned `transform_view` tries to operate on `range`, which was a *copy* of `d` and has gone out of scope. You want it to operate on `d` - and the same goes for the lambda that you currently capture by reference. That lambda ceases to exist at the end of the full expression where you call `foo`. In this case, you must store it in the inner lambda - or create it before calling `foo` to let it survive after the full expression in which you call `foo()`.

---

With forwarding of the lambda:

```cpp
template <typename RANGE, typename LAM>
auto foo(RANGE& range, LAM&& lambda) {
    return range | std::views::transform(
                       [lam = std::forward<LAM>(lambda)](const auto& element) {
                           return lam(element); 
                       });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! that works indeed. When I tried to reconstruct my actual use case I realize that it is still segfaulting. I think the extra bit I added (which I initially thought would not change the scope) is what causing the harm and therefore  likely caused by a different problem, hence I posted a separate ticket: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78085914/capturing-this-and-forwarding-the-lambda-to-another-lambda-in-conjunction-with-j

Comment: @ATK Oh, that looks interesting! I don't know much about the `{fmt}` library and won't be able to look at it today, but perhaps tomorrow.