# Capturing this and forwarding the lambda to another lambda in conjunction with fmt::join

Tags: c++, lambda, c++20, std-ranges, fmt

I previously asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084688/capturing-this-and-forwarding-the-lambda-to-another-lambda/78084736#78084736). Now I have extended it to an actual use case shown in the following example (with link [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1dY3Ex47z)):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <iostream>

template<typename RANGE, typename LAM>
auto foo(RANGE&& range, LAM&& lambda) {
    return fmt::join(range | std::views::transform( 
                [lam = std::forward<LAM>(lambda)](const auto& element) { return lam(element); }), ",");
}


class boo {
public:
    int add {2};
    
    void call_foo(){
        std::vector<int> d { 2,3,4,5,6};
        auto f = fmt::format("{}", foo(d, [this](int i) { 
            std::cout << add << std::endl;
            return add + i; 
            }));
        std::cout << f << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    boo b;
    b.call_foo();
}
```

This again results in a segfault at `std::cout << add << std::endl;`. Since it works without the `fmt::join` inside `foo`, I am suspecting that `fmt::joi`n does not cope well with what I got.
Any ideas to what the problem is and how it can be resolved

Comment: So this happens only with GCC Trunk? I used GCC 13 and it ran fine. https://godbolt.org/z/fdEqqE6rc

Comment: Yes but that is likely because of an UB. did you get the expected output ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: for `std::cout << f << std::endl;`  I expect the following output:
4,5,6,7,8

Comment: @kiner_shah address sanitizer isn't happy https://godbolt.org/z/1j58nhd8n

Comment: @AlanBirtles, yeah didn't check that. Thanks.

Comment: Including both format and fmt/format.h?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that is a mistake, although, no implications regarding my issue . I have removed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because this is broken:

```cpp
template<typename RANGE, typename LAM>
auto foo(RANGE&& range, LAM&& lambda) {
    return fmt::join(range | std::views::transform( 
                [lam = std::forward<LAM>(lambda)](const auto& element) { return lam(element); }), ",");
}
```

C++20 (and range-v3 before it) has this generalized concept of `view`, which isn't *just* an iterator/sentinel pair. It can also have arbitrary state. For `views::transform`, that state includes the function object (and of course the underlying `view`).

The problem is, `fmt::join` - while it *looks* like the other range machinery, really isn't. It just does [this](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/ae1e93d34de6caff6f318abdb06ff0db33a00792/include/fmt/ranges.h#L614-L619):

```cpp
template <typename Range>
auto join(Range&& range, string_view sep)
    -> join_view<decltype(detail::adl::adlbegin(range)),
                 decltype(detail::adl::adlend(range))> {
  return join(detail::adl::adlbegin(range), detail::adl::adlend(range), sep);
}
```

That is - it's just pulling out `begin()` and `end()` from the range and storing those, throwing away the rest of the range.

This is okay for some ranges (notably, *borrowed* ranges), but not all. A `views::transform` with a stateful transformation (as you have here) is not a borrowed range - you *need* to hold onto that callable somewhere, and this isn't happening here. Hence the problems: we're trying to invoke a function object that has already been destroyed (actually one level past that - we're trying to invoke a function object that is a member of another object that has already been destroyed, through a [dangling] pointer to that parent object).

Notably, this is only a problem because the `views::transform` actually is destroyed before it is used. If you used `fmt::join` inline with the full pipeline construction, it'd work fine:

```cpp
auto f = fmt::format("{}", fmt::join(d | std::views::transform([this](int i) { 
    std::cout << add << std::endl;
    return add + i; 
    }), ","));
```

Because the temporary `transform` isn't destroyed until the end of the full-expression, which is after all the formatting happens.

In general, it's best to only use `fmt::join` like this. And ideally we simply extend the range formatting specifiers to include a delimiter so that we just obviate the need for `fmt::join` entirely.